# Django development server hangs and suddenly does all requests on CTRL+C

Tags: django

I am using django for a REST API at my company and have a few people using the first small part of my app via a Samsung tablet. They connect via WiFi to a angular front-end on Apache, that makes API requests to my django development server.

But every now and again the server just freezes intermittently. The front end would work and you can navigate it, but no API calls are going through. And then when ever I press CTRL+C on the development server console, suddenly all the request go through. Depending on how long someone have struggle, there may be 20 API requests that all go through.

At these moments even when I change something in Django in vs-code, nothing happens server side, but when I press CTRL+C suddenly even ALL the server restarts also go through. So I can see that all the request are standing in line just waiting for the server to wake up and then they are all processed. It also looks to me if this mostly happens with the tablet (and not my desktop), where we are using Chrome.

I read that the server is now multi threaded, so that can not be the problem, and I also do not have anti-virus that can stop the server requests.

I do not really know what else to say, it has been 2 weeks of frustration now and continual searching for answer with no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by request go through, do they give correct response?

Comment: Yes, all the right responses are given. All Delete, Get and Post requests are made that should have been made. If someone was trying to log in, if I press CTRL+C 10 minutes later all the requests go through and they are logged in...

Comment: I suspect that the issue is with you using the dev server, where one request is taking too long.
If you already have apache installed you can use mod_wsgi to connect to Django like described here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Do you think this happens due to some requests taking to long? Because with the slow tablet and wifi connection I def think slow requests happen every now and again. I am setting up apache server as we speak, I was just hoping to hear the problem is the dev server, and that it will go away once I use a web server...

Comment: You should be able to check in the logs how much time the request is taking, by logging start and end time etc.
The development server is not very good at handling multiple requests at a time.

Comment: @ofnowhere Hi, this has been a long while ago, but in the end you were right about not using the dev server for just dev work. If you  feel like posting it as an answer I can mark it correct, else I would just like others to realize that using the dev server for anything more than dev work is going to give unexpected results. Using an Apache server in the end made all of this go away.

Comment: added the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is with you using the dev server, where one request is taking too long. If you already have apache installed you can use mod_wsgi to connect to Django like described here

[Django With Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04)